# How to align my text over an image

Tags: html, css

Ok, I would like to set a record for the dumbest question ever asked by a novice on EZ.
I’m trying to learn HTML / CSS on Code Academy. All is going well, except I cannot get my text to align over my image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title>My Social Network</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="contain"><a href="http://www.google.com">
            <img src="http://nl.androlib.com/appscreenmax/ppDww.u.cs.png"; id="me"></a>
            <p id="one"; text-align="center">Help</p>
        </div>
    </body>
 </html>

/*Add your CSS below!*/

.contain {
    border-color: purple;
    border-width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
 }

#me {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:100%;
    position: absolute;
}

#one {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I have genuinely been searching for a solution to this for about two hours on google, please help and feel free to take the piss. 
Also, my border is not showing up as purple.
Kindest Regards
Mugman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a style tag.

```
  <div class="contain"><a href="http://www.google.com"><img      src="http://nl.androlib.com/appscreenmax/ppDww.u.cs.png"; id="me"></a><p id="one"; text-    align="center">Help</p></div>


</body>
</html>

<style>
/*Add your CSS below!*/

.contain {
border-color: purple;
border-width: 25px;
border-style: solid;
position: absolute;
}

#me {
width:100px;
height:100px;
border-radius:100%;
position: absolute;
}

#one {
position: relative;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
}
 </style>
```